# Calculate combined odds ratio between two factors

Tags: r, odds-ratio

I am using [synergy factors](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1756-0500/2/105) to test synergy between two variables. The equation is simple enough, where $OR_{12}$ is the combined odds ratio for variables 1 and 2:

$ SF = \dfrac{OR_{12}}{(OR_1 \times OR_2)}$

How do I calculate the combined odds ratio for variables 1 and 2? I have all of the data and will calculate odds ratios by $\exp(\beta_j)$. As a side note, the odds ratios will be adjusted for other variables so I can't just use the $4 \times 2$ table as described the linked paper.

I'm guessing this is fairly simple but have not found a clear solution. Several questions on the forum address meta-analysis, but I do not want to make any mistakes or poor assumptions.

I appreciate your help!

Partial LR output:

```
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
var1          -14.09922  769.21550  -0.018  0.98538
var2           -3.38497    2.19931  -1.539  0.12378
var1:var2      -1.61902    0.57816  -2.800  0.00511
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you combine by taking the weighted average of the log of the odds ratio and then exponentiating.  If the sizes of the data sets are roughly equal for your odds ratios then it's the average of the log odds.  Some people weight just by N but I think it's recommended to use 1/SE.

**EDIT**
I didn't check your paper for what they meant by combined OR.  They mean a group of subjects that have two risk factors as opposed to either one separately.  You can't get it from the individual risk factors or an interaction in a model of the risk factors.  It's a part of the research design.  Unless your var1:var2 is that group of subjects containing both risk factors it's not what you need.  Read the methods in  the paper carefully.  The Alzheimer's example makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The betas come from the same data set and logistic regression. In that case I could just do the following: $\exp(\dfrac{\beta_1 + \beta_2}{2})$ or you said it's recommended to use 1/SE. Which SE do I use? I have added output from the regression above for clarification.

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I've made a stupid mistake. If I included the interaction between the two variables, then that is the combined log odds, right? So, to calculate SF I would do $\dfrac{\exp(-1.61902)}{\exp(-14.09922) \times \exp(-3.38497)}$

Comment: But that results in a ridiculously large number (7765253). As you can see, I'm confused...